# Rebind (or reload) Fullcalendar data through an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I want to update the events in the fullcalendar when some action is done on my UI.

My data (new) is supposed to be fetched from the server through an ajax call

Comment: It's not an issue if you want to write and answer your own question, but please ensure there isn't already an existing duplicate which covers it.

Answer (score 0):

You may refresh/ rebind the events of full calendar as follows:

```
var url = "/controller/action-method?param1=";

    $.post(url, null, 
        function (objEvents) {

            $("#fullCalendarDivId").fullCalendar('removeEvents');

            //Convert the events to fullcalendar compatible data format {title:'xxxxx', start:'2020-10-15T11:30:00', end: '2020-10-15T11:45:00'}
            var events = processEvents(objEvents);

            $("#fullCalendarDivId").fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
            $("#fullCalendarDivId").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            $("#fullCalendarDivId").fullCalendar('refetchResources');

    });
```